# Aligning Dropdown Content to Dropdown Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to solve this for the past few days now. I have a Dropdown button and some Dropdown Content. It works perfectly. The problem I am having is that the Dropdown content is not aligning with the button. It is placed anywhere but the button, depending on how the page is resized.

I guess I am doing something wrong, aa everything I have tried so far did not work correctly.

Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#dropdown')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navigator {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 82px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo h2 {
  font-size: 1.40em;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock {
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock h4 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 82px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  float: right;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: #000;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown:focus {
  background-color: #1a5dad;
  color: #fff;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown h4 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content span {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  right: 5px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content i {
  font-size: 1.10em;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content:hover {
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: #1a5dad;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .show {
  border-top: 2px solid #1a5dad;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator">
  <div id="navigator-contents">
    <div class="clock">
      <a href="#">
        <h4>Time: </h4>
        <h4>13:34</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown" onclick="myFunction()">
      <h4 id="dropdown">Home <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>This</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>Is</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>Dropdown</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>Content</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Picture of what I want to achieve: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si4rv.png)

So, my question is - How would you align the Dropdown Content with the Menu Button and make it stay there, even if it is resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to `.navigator #navigator-contents`. And add the `right` value `100px` (width of `.navigator #navigator-contents .clock`) for `.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content`

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#dropdown')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navigator {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto; position:relative
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 82px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo h2 {
  font-size: 1.40em;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock {
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock h4 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 82px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  float: right;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: #000;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown:focus {
  background-color: #1a5dad;
  color: #fff;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown h4 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 80px;     right: 100px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content span {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  right: 5px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content i {
  font-size: 1.10em;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content:hover {
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: #1a5dad;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .show {
  border-top: 2px solid #1a5dad;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator">
  <div id="navigator-contents">
    <div class="clock">
      <a href="#">
        <h4>Time: </h4>
        <h4>13:34</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown" onclick="myFunction()">
      <h4 id="dropdown">Home <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>This</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>Is</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>Dropdown</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="drop-content">
          <span>Content</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below. I made id `myDropdown` a child of id `dropdown` to take advantage of the absolute positioning. Now `myDropdown` is positioned absolutely at the right side with a value of zero.

Furthermore, I changed `myDropdown` into a flexbox.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#dropdown')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navigator {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  float: left;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 82px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .logo h2 {
  font-size: 1.40em;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock {
  float: right;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .clock h4 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 82px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  float: right;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: #000;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown:focus {
  background-color: #1a5dad;
  color: #fff;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown h4 {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content {
  padding: 30px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content span {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  right: 5px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content i {
  font-size: 1.10em;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .dropdown-content .drop-content:hover {
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: #1a5dad;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.navigator #navigator-contents .show {
  border-top: 2px solid #1a5dad;
  display: flex;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigator">
  <div id="navigator-contents">
    <div class="clock">
      <a href="#">
        <h4>Time: </h4>
        <h4>13:34</h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown" onclick="myFunction()">
      <h4 id="dropdown">Home <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>

      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#">
          <div class="drop-content">
            <span>This</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="drop-content">
            <span>Is</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="drop-content">
            <span>Dropdown</span>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="drop-content">
            <span>Content</span>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```